# JBoss 7.1.1 + ElasticCache?

Tags: jboss, redis, memcached, jboss7.x, amazon-elasticache

I am deploying my Java EE application (JBoss 7.1.1) on AWS, what I am missing now is cache... I can't seem to find any documentation on how to replace or duplicate Infinispan cache with Memcached or Redis non-programatically (I can't change anything in the code)... Anyone?

My guess is I should do something in my standalone.xml ...around here?

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.2" default-cache-container="hibernate">
     <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query">
           <local-cache name="entity">
                <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
           </local-cache>
           <local-cache name="local-query">
                <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="timestamps">
                <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
            </local-cache>
     </cache-container>
</subsystem>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tachú,

there is no out-of-the-box support for Redis/Memcached in JBoss but Infinispan 8 can use Redis as cache store, see http://blog.infinispan.org/2015/09/new-redis-cache-store-introduced-in.html

HTH, Mark